# iPad Safari Audio element play() success but cannot hear actual audio

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, safari, html5-audio

Before this question gets marked as duplicate for the age old problem of safari not auto playing audio, I would like to mention it's not that.

Now, I'm having the following audio element created with javascript:

```
self.audioElem = new Audio();
self.audioElem.src = audioUrl; //This is fetched from server, but this is fetched at page load itself and NOT when user clicks play.
```

Then there is this function called `playAudio()`:

```
var playPromise = self.audioElem.play();
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
   playPromise
     .then(function () {
        alert("Playback started!");
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
        alert("Playback failed.");
      })
}
```

The alert "Playback started!" actually gets fired and the audio plays out, but if I remove the alert or even press OK on the alert, the audio stops playing and if I print out the audio status parameters, this is it,

`paused` : `false`,

`duration` : `6`,

`buffered` : `6`,

`currentTime` : `0`,

How is it that the paused can be `false` and `currentTime` can always be zero (I've tried printing these on setInterval). If I go to the lockscreen I see the audio length being 6 seconds and the audio is in playing state. But the seekbar is not even moving. And IT IS A VALID AUDIO (mp3 format).

PS: 1. This happens only on iPad and works perfectly fine on iPhones. Is safari on iPad any different? 2. If I just let the alert stay, the full audio is playing perfectly, only if I remove the alert or if I press ok it stops.

Comment: From what i know, alerts will delegate focus from the actual webpage, to the native browser itself so the page will lose focus. Perhaps try making a visual popup within html like a div or so, that the feeling will be a popup but not being a native popup

Comment: @Jayr The audio when alert is turned on is working perfectly fine, the problem is when the alert is switched off. Ideally I don't want that alert to be present.

Comment: Like i said, the the browser tab is not active and focused out. Try using logs check if it still give the same error